# Add rule mark on top of multiple layers

Tags: vega-lite

I'm pretty new to Vega/Deneb and can't figure out how to add a global rule mark to my chart.
When I add it as a new layer, it displays a rule mark for each bar (see code below)
Can somebody help?

Many thanks !

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 1}, {"a": "B", "b": 1}, {"a": "C", "b": 0.7455},
      {"a": "D", "b": 0.8}, {"a": "E", "b": 0.9402}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": null
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"format": ".0%", "values": [0, 0.5, 1]}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": {"expr": "datum.b < 0.95 ? '#910049' : '#00477e'"},
        "tooltip": true
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "right", "dx": -5},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "b",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "format": ".0%"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type":"text", "align": "left", "dx": 5},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"datum": 0},
        "text": {
          "field": "a",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"datum": 0.95}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to add the rule mark in the layer, resulting in the screenshot below :
{
"mark": "rule",
"encoding": {
"x": {"datum": 0.95}
}
}
[In the layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn5sT.png)

I tried to add the rule mark after the layer array, but it messed everything up :
"mark": "rule",
"encoding": {
"x": {"datum": 0.95}
}
[After the layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ug6L.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"a": "A", "b": 1},
          {"a": "B", "b": 1},
          {"a": "C", "b": 0.7455},
          {"a": "D", "b": 0.8},
          {"a": "E", "b": 0.9402}
        ]
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
            "x": {
              "field": "b",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": {"format": ".0%", "values": [0, 0.5, 1]}
            }
          },
          "layer": [
            {
              "mark": {
                "type": "bar",
                "color": {"expr": "datum.b < 0.95 ? '#910049' : '#00477e'"},
                "tooltip": true
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "align": "right",
                "dx": -5,
                "color": "white"
              },
              "encoding": {
                "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".0%"}
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": {
                "type": "text",
                "align": "left",
                "dx": 5,
                "color": "white"
              },
              "encoding": {
                "x": {"datum": 0},
                "text": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
     {
      "data": {"values": [{}]},
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 0.95}},
      "layer": [
        {"mark": {"type": "rule", "stroke":"red", "strokeWidth":2, "strokeDash":[1,2]}}
      
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks David!
Just for my understanding, why would the data be inside the layer?

Comment: Vega will plot a mark for each data point. If the data is in a layer, it will only plot for the marks in that same layer hierarchy. The rule mark is in a different layer hierarchy and so won't plot 5 different lines. Don't forget to mark as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here we go.

David's answer is the best solution.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 1},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": 0.7455},
      {"a": "D", "b": 0.8},
      {"a": "E", "b": 0.9402}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": null},
    "x": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"format": ".0%", "values": [0, 0.5, 1]}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"x": 0.95, "y": "0", "y2": "1"}]},
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "strokeDash": [4, 2], "color": "#00477e"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {
          "field": "y",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null,
          "scale": {"domainMin": -1}
        },
        "y2": {"field": "y2"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": {"expr": "datum.b < 0.95 ? '#910049' : '#00477e'"},
        "tooltip": true
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "right", "dx": -5, "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".0%"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 5, "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 0}, "text": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"}}
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```

Let us know how you get along.
Adam

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I've supplied another way without having to set the y and y2 positions below.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible with a line mark instead of rule but the line doesn't scale across the entire chart.

**David's answer is the best though!**

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 1},
      {"a": "B", "b": 1},
      {"a": "C", "b": 0.7455},
      {"a": "D", "b": 0.8},
      {"a": "E", "b": 0.9402}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"format": ".0%", "values": [0, 0.5, 1]}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": {"expr": "datum.b < 0.95 ? '#910049' : '#00477e'"},
        "tooltip": true
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeDash": [2, 2], "strokeWidth": 2},
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 0.95, "type": "quantitative"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "right", "dx": -5, "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".0%"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "dx": 5, "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 0}, "text": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"}}
    }
  ],
  "config": {}
}
```